# Got this no-name Japanese-made J-bass off a guy for $50. Help me identify it?

Tags: electric-bass-guitar

In case it helps he said that he's had it sitting on the wall of his garage for about 15 years or so so that might help date it.

[image: image of electric bass]

Also, as a side note, this thing is super messed up. The pickup closest to the bridge doesn't work and the truss rod is loose or broken (turns freely) so the bottom eight frets are unusable because the neck is a bit bent. But it's great for a beginner like me to practice on! :D Hell, I could've held off on buying the brand new Jackson I impulse bought when he told me he couldn't repair it lol

Comment: Although this type of question (doing background on an instrument) is off-topic here on the main site, you might get some answers in the chat room. There are a number of bass players who are knowledgeable. After you've posted there, you could leave a comment here so that irregular chat participants will know to look there.

Comment: I found this on a reverb.com, almost identical to yours: https://reverb.com/item/58051673-made-in-japan-fender-jazz-bass-copy-1969-sunburst-lawsuit-bass?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=18045925166&utm_content=campaignid=18045925166_adgroupid=143121795754_productpartitionid=1897422473174=merchantid=558526608_productid=58051673_keyword=_device=c_adposition=_matchtype=_creative=616435425580&gclid=Cj0KCQiA4OybBhCzARIsAIcfn9l_U6mnaS7d9aSzESmW6aUSumOB8rumtdFAkAHLXqttMzjL6ZpLDi4aAtFQEALw_wcB Including the Fender shaped headstock that looks a little too wide on the G string side.

Comment: A loose truss rod can be a broken truss rod. If turning it has an effect it may be ok. The pickup may be a minor issue. If you can’t have a pro look at it (your best bet) then look at some DIY bass setup videos on YouTube. The ones by John Carruthers are very good. You can probably find a video to figure out if the pickup works too. Your post is very unclear, “bottom eight fronts are usable” (?) This bass can have some potential if it is able to be set up and repaired.

Comment: I'm not sure if practicing on a half-unplayable instrument is a great idea for a beginner. It can be great if you can already play and work around or live with the instrument's limitations but learning to play is difficult enough without extra challenges.

Comment: Sounds like a great instrument for learning about how to fix it. My first bass came with a broken neck, amongst other faults. Learning how to improve such a bass can only be a good thing, and if you wreck it completely (highly unlikely) $50 won't hurt too much.